# svg rendered with square behind when bootstrap is imported

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, bootstrap-5

I am using reactJS + bootstrap.

Since I imported bootstrap, squares appeared behind my svg...

[image]

does anybody know what are these ? and how can I disable them ? I think I need to override a bootstrap property but don't know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like svg's are wrapped in  element. Try removing borders on buttons

```
button{
  border:none;
}
```